# not able to read a file with getline() properly

Tags: c++

I have read many posts but whatever i do, i cant get rid of the problem.
My input file is like below

> ```
> getData
> getData,value1,value2
> ```

```
string value, line;
while (getline(inFile, line)) {
line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());
stringstream linestream(line);
getline(linestream, value, ',');
Logging::PrintInfo("Got Request3 %s.\n",value.c_str());
}
```

I get the print as

> ```
> Got Request3 getData --> first loop
> Got Request3 ta  -->second loop.
> ```

The initial characters are being cut from the string.

I have tried the below also for trimming the \r, but still the problem exists.

```
if ( line.size() && line[line.size()-1] == '\r' ) {
            //line1 = line.substr( 0, line.size() - 1 );}

        line.erase(0, line.find_first_not_of("\r"));
        line.erase(line.find_last_not_of("\r")+1);
```

Tried doing

```
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\n'), line.end());
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\t'), line.end());
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\f'), line.end());
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\v'), line.end());
    line.erase(line.begin(), std::find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<char>(), ' ')));
    line.erase(std::find_if(line.rbegin(), line.rend(), std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<char>(), ' ')).base(), line.end());
```

But my issue is not resolved. First few characters are still lost. After multiple tries I found that the issue is with \r. But I still have a problem.

As soon as I remove the \r, my next line string gets cut. But if I do not cut it, my first line has a \r and that's not being processed.

Comment: What are you trying do with this: `line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());`?

Comment: Trying to remove the \r carriage return

Comment: line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r'), line.end());
  line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\n'), line.end());
  line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\t'), line.end());
  line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\f'), line.end());
  line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\v'), line.end());
  line.erase(line.begin(), std::find_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<char>(), ' ')));
  line.erase(std::find_if(line.rbegin(), line.rend(), std::bind1st(std::not_equal_to<char>(), ' ')).base(), line.end());

Comment: Hint:  read up on the return value from [std::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: Hint 2:  Refactor code without nested function calls, use temporary variables.

Comment: not sure what your issue is, code seems to work fine, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98966298b87ba6ca)

Comment: Guess the issue is with the input file i am using.

Comment: i just tried with line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '\r\n'), line.end()); This is reading the token properly now. But i still see some issue though

Comment: .ot Request3 getOrder
Now my first letter is replaced with a .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fragment for parsing the data file:

```
std::string token_1_line_1;
std::string token_1_line_2;
std::string token_2_line_2;
std::string token_3_line_2;
std::string text_line;

while (inFile >> token_1_line_1) // Read text w/o line ending
{
  getline(inFile, token_1_line_2, ',');
  getline(inFile, token_2_line_2, ',');
  getline(inFile, token_3_line_3);
}
```

*Note: the above code has not been tested.*